# How to drag and drop a particular cell between columns?

Tags: grid, cells, dhtmlx

I have two grids with DHTMLX. I want to pick one row from first and drag it to the other table. When I drop the row, the information stays in a particular cell.

If I have, for example, 3 columns like `ID`, `TEXT`, and `NUMBER`, I would like to stay in the second table in a particular cell and this say for example `ID-TEXT-NUMBER`.

I can move rows between tables, but not one cell only.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the cell dragging is not supported in the dhtmlxGrid.